# Error en SpringBoot creando una APIRest

Tags: java, spring, rest

escribo aquí para ver si pueden ayudarme con este error.
No se que es lo que está mal, intente todo y no pude solucionarlo. Dejo mi codigo y el error

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
[2m2021-12-23 18:06:44.693[0;39m [31mERROR[0;39m [35m1084[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36mo.s.boot.SpringApplication              [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'characterController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'characServ'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'characterService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'characRep'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'ICharacter' defined in com.alkemyApi.app.repository.ICharacter defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on AlkemyApiApplication: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: class java.lang.Character
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:659) ~[spring-beans-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:639) ~[spring-beans-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:119) ~[spring-beans-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:399) ~[spring-beans-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1431) ~[spring-beans-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:619) ~[spring-beans-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:944) ~[spring-beans-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:918) ~[spring-context-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583) ~[spring-context-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:145) ~[spring-boot-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:754) ~[spring-boot-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:434) ~[spring-boot-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:338) ~[spring-boot-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1343) ~[spring-boot-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1332) ~[spring-boot-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
at com.alkemyApi.app.AlkemyApiApplication.main(AlkemyApiApplication.java:15) ~[classes/:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) ~[spring-boot-devtools-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'characterService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'characRep'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'ICharacter' defined in com.alkemyApi.app.repository.ICharacter defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on AlkemyApiApplication: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: class java.lang.Character
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:659) ~[spring-beans-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:639) ~[spring-beans-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:119) ~[spring-beans-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:399) ~[spring-beans-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1431) ~[spring-beans-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:619) ~[spring-beans-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276) ~[spring-beans-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1380) ~[spring-beans-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1300) ~[spring-beans-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:656) ~[spring-beans-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
... 25 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'ICharacter' defined in com.alkemyApi.app.repository.ICharacter defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on AlkemyApiApplication: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: class java.lang.Character
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1804) ~[spring-beans-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:620) ~[spring-beans-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276) ~[spring-beans-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1380) ~[spring-beans-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1300) ~[spring-beans-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:656) ~[spring-beans-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
... 39 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: class java.lang.Character
at org.hibernate.metamodel.internal.MetamodelImpl.managedType(MetamodelImpl.java:582) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
at org.hibernate.metamodel.internal.MetamodelImpl.managedType(MetamodelImpl.java:85) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaMetamodelEntityInformation.(JpaMetamodelEntityInformation.java:75) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaEntityInformationSupport.getEntityInformation(JpaEntityInformationSupport.java:66) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getEntityInformation(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:228) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getTargetRepository(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:178) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getTargetRepository(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:161) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getTargetRepository(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:72) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:319) ~[spring-data-commons-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.lambda$afterPropertiesSet$5(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:323) ~[spring-data-commons-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.getNullable(Lazy.java:230) ~[spring-data-commons-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.get(Lazy.java:114) ~[spring-data-commons-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:329) ~[spring-data-commons-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.java:144) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1863) ~[spring-beans-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1800) ~[spring-beans-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
... 49 common frames omitted

Mi entidad

```
package com.alkemyApi.app.entity;
    
    import java.util.List;
    
    import javax.persistence.Basic;
    import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
    import javax.persistence.Entity;
    import javax.persistence.FetchType;
    import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
    import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
    import javax.persistence.Id;
    import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
    import javax.persistence.JoinTable;
    import javax.persistence.ManyToMany;
    import javax.persistence.Table;
    
    import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonManagedReference;
    
    @Entity
    @Table(name="characters")
    public class Character {
    
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
        private long id_character;
        
        @Basic
        private int age;
        private String image;
        private String history;
        private double weight;
        
        @JsonManagedReference
        @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
        @JoinTable(name="characters_shooting",
        joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name="id_character", nullable=false)},
        inverseJoinColumns= {@JoinColumn(name="id_shooting", nullable=false)})
        private List<Shooting> shootingList;
    
        public Character(long id_character, int age, String image, String history, double weight,
                List<Shooting> shootingList) {
            super();
            this.id_character = id_character;
            this.age = age;
            this.image = image;
            this.history = history;
            this.weight = weight;
            this.shootingList = shootingList;
        }
```

Servicios;
Interfaz

```
package com.alkemyApi.app.service;
    
    import java.util.List;
    
    public interface ICharacterService {
    
        public void saveCharacters(Character character);
        public void deleteCharacters(Character character);
        public List<Character> findAllCharacters();
        public Character findCharactersById(long id);
    }
```

Clase:

```
package com.alkemyApi.app.service;
    
    import java.util.List;
    import java.util.Optional;
    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
    
    import com.alkemyApi.app.repository.ICharacter;
    @Service
    public class CharacterService implements ICharacterService {
    
        @Autowired
        private ICharacter characRep;
        
        @Override
        public void saveCharacters(Character character) {
            characRep.save(character);
        }
    
        @Override
        public void deleteCharacters(Character character) {
            characRep.delete(character);
        }
    
        @Override
        public List<Character> findAllCharacters() {
            List<Character> listCharacters = characRep.findAll();
            return listCharacters;
        }
    
        @Override
        public Character findCharactersById(long id) {
            Optional<Character> opt = characRep.findById(id);
            Character character = null;
            if(opt.isPresent()) {
                character = opt.get();
            }else {
                throw new RuntimeException("Character doesn't exist.");
            }
            return character;
        }
        
    
    }
```

Controlador:

```
    package com.alkemyApi.app.controller;
    
    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
    
    import com.alkemyApi.app.service.ICharacterService;
    
    @RestController
    @RequestMapping(value = "character")
    public class CharacterController {
        
        @Autowired
        private ICharacterService characServ;
        
        @PostMapping("/save")
        public void saveCharacter(@RequestBody Character character) {
            characServ.saveCharacters(character);
            System.out.println("Character successfully saved");
        }
    
    }
```

Repositorio

```
    package com.alkemyApi.app.controller;
    
    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
    
    import com.alkemyApi.app.service.ICharacterService;
    
    @RestController
    @RequestMapping(value = "character")
    public class CharacterController {
        
        @Autowired
        private ICharacterService characServ;
        
        @PostMapping("/save")
        public void saveCharacter(@RequestBody Character character) {
            characServ.saveCharacters(character);
            System.out.println("Character successfully saved");
        }
    
    }
```

Gracias, espero su ayuda

Comment: Diría que tu repositorio y controller se parecen demasiado :) Hasta me atrevería a decir que has pegado dos veces el controller. Por cierto, tu clase `Shooting` también es una entity? Porque si no es una entity dudo que te permita hacerle un manytomany así, lo mismo tendrías que usar embebed o alguna otra anotación

Comment: Por cierto, esto ya no tiene mucho que ver con tu error pero ... si vas a usar optionals puedes evitar escribir tanto código y hacerlo así: `return characRep.findById(id).orElseThrow(new RuntimeException("blablabla");` Esa línea en vez de todo el código de tu `findCharactersById` :)

Comment: Hola Benito, por error coloqué dos veces mi controller, igualmente mi clase Repository solo tiene la anotacion Repository, y extiende a la clase JpaRepository<Character, Long>, ppr otro lado la clase Shooting tiene la anotación de Entity. Probé con embebed pero sigue dandome el mismo error. Nose con que mas puedo probar, desde ya muchas gracias!